# How to send Date Value from TextBox to Server Script in app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have this code:

Client script:

```
function sendMessage() {  

var page = app.pages.PAGE1.root.descendants;

  google.script.run

  .sendDate(page.date.value);

}
```

Server script:

```
function sendDate(date) {

  var doc=DocumentApp.create('document');
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph('TEXT ' +date);

  doc.saveAndClose();

  var url=doc.getUrl();    
  var email=Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, doc.getName(), 'Link to your  doc: ' +doc.getUrl()); 
}
```

But, when I run I have an error.

Please help me.

Comment: Please add more description to your question, such as what type of error it gives you. Also, please include proper formatting for code. I attempted to add this formatting myself, but for SO it said the question had too much code to apply this edit.

Comment: This is my error: Failed due to illegal value in property

Comment: Maybe edit your question to include your error. Also since you are using DocumentApp and MailApp in your server script it would help to know if your error occurs with your client script or your server script. It might be best to include a screenshot of your error or a description on which line of code the error occurs, which should appear in your console.

Comment: See the following ... https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/server

It explicitly states .... "A request would fail if you attempted to pass a Date object".  What seems to be suggested is to pass a portable representation such as a number (eg. seconds from epoch) or string (eg. ISO 8601).